# Tor Encryption Standards

Tags: onion-services, encryption

I'm looking for up-to-date information on Tor encryption standards, and I can't seem to find anything newer than 2013.

[What encryption algorithms does Tor use?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9447/what-encryption-algorithms-does-tor-use)

[What is the reasoning behind keeping hidden service onion RSA keys at 1024 length?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/760/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-keeping-hidden-service-onion-rsa-keys-at-1024-lengt?rq=1)

[Hidden .onion service with 2048 bit (or 4096 bit) RSA private key -- how to host it?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/hidden-onion-service-with-2048-bit-or-4096-bit-rsa-private-key-how-to-host)

Everything I've been able to find links back to a proposal to move to Ed25519 keys: https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-dev/2013-August/005259.html

Poking around in my own Tor relay, I found a master public and master secret ed25519 key, along with a signing cert and signing secret key. However, there's also a secret_id_key and a couple of secret_onion* keys that are RSA private keys.

Does Tor 2.7 use Ed25519, or 1024-bit RSA? Why are there 2 kinds of keys? How secure is Ed25519 compared to 1024-bit or 2048-bit RSA?

Thanks in advance,

Tristan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two keys are not for substituting each other, but to make "an authenticating pair", unique for every relay. 1024-bit-**only** RSA is an anachronism, I hope higher lengths will be added ASAP in the light of quantum computing era *actual* start and first really working application that are working/starting-to-work nowdays. *I wonder what are they trying to crack ;)* A different algos for different keys is a good approach, actually - it's harder to crack multiple algos than one. If even RSA1024 will be owned, ed25519 will still be a problem for an attacker. A good [crypto-related spec](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt) is an official one, so take some time and read it throughfully - I myself was misunderstanding it after a first quick reading.

About comparisions : RSA vs EC is well-compared subject, I leave to a mathematical Googling about it : too broad to just point to some pieces of research not mentioning another ones.

Feel free to ask further questions - I'm glad to help!

You're welcome,

Alexey

Comment: Thanks for the info. I re-read the tor-spec, and I think I found what I was looking for in 0.3: Ciphers. "For a public-key cipher, we use RSA with 1024-bit keys... For the 'ntor' handshake, we also use the Curve25519 elliptic curve group." So it looks like Tor uses a mix of the 2. I suppose it's still secure because of the layered encryption, but I wouldn't mind seeing 2048-bit RSA coming to Tor.

Comment: @SuperSluether I'm working on a privacy-targeted Linux distro myself now, and one of my sides of development is GPU hw acceleration for mass-crypto operations. Until accelerated, RSA1024 is a *sane compromise*, I'm afraid : an experimentation with 2048 bit key ended with a amall lag, 4096 bits were causing eye-catched problems, no special tools were required to notice it